# ISPN000188: Error while processing a commit in a two-phase transaction: org.infinispan.marshall.NotSerializableException

Tags: jboss7.x, infinispan

I getting following error in my `server.log` after deployed my application in JBoss and while trying to login this error occurs....

Basically JBoss says two-phase commit fails while inifinispan tries to marshal the object.... it raises the exception`NotSerializableException`...

Consequently, `JBoss-Infinispan` says `DummyTransaction.java:287` `ISPN000111: afterCompletion() failed for SynchronizationAdapter`

```
13:28:38,186 ERROR [org.infinispan.transaction.TransactionCoordinator] (http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-3) ISPN000188: Error while processing a commit in a two-phase transaction: org.infinispan.marshall.NotSerializableException: com.singtel.um.transaction.TransactionManager
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
       in field transactionManager
       in object java.util.HashMap@f1852ac6
       in object org.jboss.as.clustering.SimpleMarshalledValue@f1852ac6
              -> toString = {User=com.singtel.um.dto.UserDto@4c08e73b, Userid=1, Username=sysadmin, org.apache.struts.action.LOCALE=en_US, Response=com.singtel.um.dto.ResponsePageDto@72c5cec1, userManager=com.singtel.um.UserManager@418634d5}
       in object org.infinispan.util.FastCopyHashMap@373deff8
              -> toString = {0=11, 1=1444195716345, 2=org.jboss.as.clustering.web.DistributableSessionMetadata@40843124, 3={User=com.singtel.um.dto.UserDto@4c08e73b, Userid=1, Username=sysadmin, org.apache.struts.action.LOCALE=en_US, Response=com.singtel.um.dto.ResponsePageDto@72c5cec1, userManager=com.singtel.um.UserManager@418634d5}}
       in object org.infinispan.atomic.AtomicHashMap@3345fa74
              -> toString = AtomicHashMap
       in object org.infinispan.container.entries.ImmortalCacheEntry@cca5812b
              -> toString = ImmortalCacheEntry{key=ZVx0ehVWVUvmITSBGMT9pQmB, value=ImmortalCacheValue {value=AtomicHashMap}}
       in object org.infinispan.loaders.bucket.Bucket@18891bc5
              -> toString = Bucket{entries={ZVx0ehVWVUvmITSBGMT9pQmB=ImmortalCacheEntry{key=ZVx0ehVWVUvmITSBGMT9pQmB, value=ImmortalCacheValue {value=AtomicHashMap}}}, bucketId='1607025664'}

13:28:38,210 INFO  [stdout] (http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-3) ERROR [http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-3] (TransactionCoordinator.java:213) - ISPN000188: Error while processing a commit in a two-phase transaction
13:28:38,213 INFO  [stdout] (http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-3) org.infinispan.marshall.NotSerializableException: com.singtel.um.transaction.TransactionManager
13:28:38,216 INFO  [stdout] (http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-3) Caused by: an exception which occurred:
13:28:38,218 INFO  [stdout] (http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-3)      in field transactionManager
13:28:38,219 INFO  [stdout] (http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-3)      in object java.util.HashMap@f1852ac6
13:28:38,221 INFO  [stdout] (http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-3)      in object org.jboss.as.clustering.SimpleMarshalledValue@f1852ac6
13:28:38,224 INFO  [stdout] (http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-3)             -> toString = {User=com.singtel.um.dto.UserDto@4c08e73b, Userid=1, Username=sysadmin, org.apache.struts.action.LOCALE=en_US, Response=com.singtel.um.dto.ResponsePageDto@72c5cec1, userManager=com.singtel.um.UserManager@418634d5}
13:28:38,228 INFO  [stdout] (http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-3)      in object org.infinispan.util.FastCopyHashMap@373deff8
13:28:38,231 INFO  [stdout] (http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-3)             -> toString = {0=11, 1=1444195716345, 2=org.jboss.as.clustering.web.DistributableSessionMetadata@40843124, 3={User=com.singtel.um.dto.UserDto@4c08e73b, Userid=1, Username=sysadmin, org.apache.struts.action.LOCALE=en_US, Response=com.singtel.um.dto.ResponsePageDto@72c5cec1, userManager=com.singtel.um.UserManager@418634d5}}
13:28:38,237 INFO  [stdout] (http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-3)      in object org.infinispan.atomic.AtomicHashMap@3345fa74
13:28:38,239 INFO  [stdout] (http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-3)             -> toString = AtomicHashMap
13:28:38,241 INFO  [stdout] (http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-3)      in object org.infinispan.container.entries.ImmortalCacheEntry@cca5812b
13:28:38,243 INFO  [stdout] (http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-3)             -> toString = ImmortalCacheEntry{key=ZVx0ehVWVUvmITSBGMT9pQmB, value=ImmortalCacheValue {value=AtomicHashMap}}
13:28:38,246 INFO  [stdout] (http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-3)      in object org.infinispan.loaders.bucket.Bucket@18891bc5
13:28:38,249 INFO  [stdout] (http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-3)             -> toString = Bucket{entries={ZVx0ehVWVUvmITSBGMT9pQmB=ImmortalCacheEntry{key=ZVx0ehVWVUvmITSBGMT9pQmB, value=ImmortalCacheValue {value=AtomicHashMap}}}, bucketId='1607025664'}
13:28:38,253 ERROR [org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyTransaction] (http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-3) ISPN000111: afterCompletion() failed for SynchronizationAdapter{localTransaction=LocalTransaction{remoteLockedNodes=null, isMarkedForRollback=false, lockedKeys=null, backupKeyLocks=null, topologyId=-1, isFromStateTransfer=false} org.infinispan.transaction.synchronization.SyncLocalTransaction@42} org.infinispan.transaction.synchronization.SynchronizationAdapter@61: org.infinispan.CacheException: Could not commit.
       at org.infinispan.transaction.synchronization.SynchronizationAdapter.afterCompletion(SynchronizationAdapter.java:83)
       at org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyTransaction.notifyAfterCompletion(DummyTransaction.java:285)
       at org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyTransaction.runCommitTx(DummyTransaction.java:334)
       at org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyTransaction.commit(DummyTransaction.java:91)
       at org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyBaseTransactionManager.commit(DummyBaseTransactionManager.java:102)
       at org.jboss.as.clustering.web.impl.TransactionBatchingManager.endBatch(TransactionBatchingManager.java:75)
       at org.jboss.as.web.session.DistributableSessionManager.processSessionRepl(DistributableSessionManager.java:1574) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
       at org.jboss.as.web.session.DistributableSessionManager.storeSession(DistributableSessionManager.java:872) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
       at org.jboss.as.web.session.InstantSnapshotManager.snapshot(InstantSnapshotManager.java:47) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
       at org.jboss.as.web.session.ClusteredSessionValve.handleRequest(ClusteredSessionValve.java:142) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
       at org.jboss.as.web.session.ClusteredSessionValve.invoke(ClusteredSessionValve.java:99) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
       at org.jboss.as.web.session.JvmRouteValve.invoke(JvmRouteValve.java:92) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
       at org.jboss.as.web.session.LockingValve.invoke(LockingValve.java:64) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
       at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
       at org.infinispan.transaction.TransactionCoordinator.handleCommitFailure(TransactionCoordinator.java:224)
       at org.infinispan.transaction.TransactionCoordinator.commit(TransactionCoordinator.java:185)
       at org.infinispan.transaction.synchronization.SynchronizationAdapter.afterCompletion(SynchronizationAdapter.java:81)
       ... 21 more

13:28:38,308 INFO  [stdout] (http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-3) ERROR [http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-3] (DummyTransaction.java:287) - ISPN000111: afterCompletion() failed for SynchronizationAdapter{localTransaction=LocalTransaction{remoteLockedNodes=null, isMarkedForRollback=false, lockedKeys=null, backupKeyLocks=null, topologyId=-1, isFromStateTransfer=false} org.infinispan.transaction.synchronization.SyncLocalTransaction@42} org.infinispan.transaction.synchronization.SynchronizationAdapter@61
13:28:38,317 INFO  [stdout] (http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-3) org.infinispan.CacheException: Could not commit.
```

Please someone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your classes (not sure what's the name but it holds `com.singtel.um.dto.ResponsePageDto`, `com.singtel.um.dto.UserDto`, and `com.singtel.um.UserManager`) seems to have a field `transactionManager`, and your TM implementation is not serializable. You should make that field transient.

Not sure why the `HashMap` is in the stack, though, unless something is instrumenting Java classes.

Ideally, you should also use `Externalizable` or `AdvancedExternalizer` to optimize serialization of your objects. See [Infinispan User Guide](http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_advanced_externalizers)

Comment: what is implication of null value with respect to serialization.... ignore my question if it is vague.... I read understood your answer..... let me explore my code and fix.... Thanks, Anand

Comment: Thanks for your reply.... I commented inifinspan `<subsystem/>`, even after the error persists.... When disable that my log was bit clear and I found these... `20:07:35,140 INFO  [stdout] (http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-1) group id is: 0` 
`20:07:35,141 INFO  [stdout] (http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-1) group id in request is: null` 
`20:07:35,142 INFO  [stdout] (http-/192.nnn.nnn.nn:8080-1) 1 groupid=null`

Comment: in spite of `inifinispan` error in `server.log` code is functioning as expected... i hope it is becauase `infinispan` is just a caching platform for jboss..... i don't know what was the problem in my last deployment.... it is through and working now with `inifinispan` error......

Comment: Thanks for get to know about another newer `class`,- `AdvancedExternalizer` which I'm unaware of.....